# Facebook Login link redirects straight back to my application without ever showing login dialog

Tags: facebook, redirect, oauth

I am attempting to implement a simple Facebook login flow for a web application using HTTP redirects, as detailed at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.2.

For the purposes of making this question generic, let's say the application URL is `www.example.com/app.php`. On the application page, there is a link which directs users to Facebook's OAuth endpoint, where ideally:

- they log in to Facebook (if not already logged in) and approve my application permission to access their public profile
- they are then redirected back to my application's URL along with some extra parameters appended (e.g. `www.example.com/app.php?code=...&access_token=...` if the login was successful, or `www.example.com/app.php?error_reason=...&error=...&error_description=...` if login/app approval was unsuccessful)

The Facebook OAuth endpoint is:

`www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=12345&redirect_uri=www.xyz.com/app.php`

where I have filled in the `client_id` and `redirect_uri` parameters with my application's ID and my application's URL respectively.

What actually happens whenever I access the link is that it immediately redirects back to my application's homepage - without ever showing a login dialog of any kind. This happens with Firefox and with Chrome - both when I am logged in to Facebook and when I am not, in normal sessions and in incognito sessions with no plugins enabled. From the browser inspector, I can see that the Facebook OAuth page is definitely requested but is straight away 302 redirecting to my application page with just a `code` parameter appended.

`www.example.com/app.php?code=...`

This also happens when the Facebook OAuth link is accessed from pages other than my application's URL (e.g. if I click the link from `www.example.com/other_page.htm`).

I am unsure what I am doing wrong here; the application URL (`www.example.com/app.php`) is approved on my app dashboard in as many places as I could find, and changing the `request_uri` parameter to any other URL results in an error page. I have also tried `urlencode()`ing my application URL before passing it in the `request_uri` parameter, but the result remains the same. I don't know what to try next as as far as I can tell I have followed Facebook's manual login guide as closely as possible.

Comment: After receiving the code parameter in your application, are you exchanging it to receive the access token as described in the guide you linked here?

Comment: @PatrickLC as far I understand the guide, I think that the `code` parameter is just a unique string related to each login request, and that there should be some more fragments appended to my application's URL on the redirect (e.g. `access_token` or `error`) rather than having to further use the returned `code` parameter in any way

Comment: @PatrickLC you are right, the `code` parameter does have to be exchanged for an access token, but I am still confused why there is the Facebook OAuth link redirects straight away without a login flow of any kind

Comment: Yeah, but i lost the focus, if you are not logged in Facebook, then using the url: www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=12345&redirect_uri=www.xyz.com/app.php must show you the facebook login, could be possible to include your real url just to test?

Comment: Good news! It's working fine, it prompts for facebook login, "QuizSummativeApp will receive the following info: your public profile." and then redirects fine to your app.

Comment: @PatrickLC Great! Thanks for confirming it is working; it is still redirecting straight away for me so I am guessing there is some problem on my end, so I will keep investigating and hopefully post a solution of some sort once I figure out what's wrong